# Assumptions and pitfalls in competing risks model

Tags: survival, cox-model

Question: **What are the major pitfalls and assumptions for competing risk analysis?**

*Background*

I'm trying to learn competing risks and I use the `cmprsk` package in R based upon Gray's algorithm. I've read Melania Pintilie's book, [Competing Risks: A practical perspective](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470870680), but although it's a very nice introduction to the field I lack a list of the common pitfalls. My mentor has warned me about the competing risk analysis still being a developing field and I would therefore really appreciate if I could get your opinions on this.

In the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11516/shall-i-censor-or-rather-remove-other-causes-in-cause-specific-survival-analysis) it's mentioned:

> just make sure that you understand what assumptions you are making

As I understand it the major assumption is the proportional hazards, similar to the Cox model, but other than that assumption I'm not sure that I know what other assumptions and pitfalls I'm to look out for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pintile's book is an excellent book for understanding competing risks but if you want to study theoretical side of the competing risks, take a look at Martin J. Crowder's book, [Classical Competing Risks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584881755).

I wrote my master's thesis on competing risks and from what I remember, they are some drawbacks/disadvantages when competing risks analysis is conducted. The most well-known problem is an [issue of identifiability](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1403768?uid=3739920&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=56110235813). There were many papers and journals regarding this issue when I was preparing my thesis and I believe many scholars are still writing papers about this.

The issue of identifiability arises due to the nature of competing risks modelling -- when death or failure has observed from an identifiable cause-of-failure it cannot occur again later from another case.

Another issue arises when the cause of failure for a subject or unit is NOT precisely identified, it can be narrowed down to a subset of the potential risks. This phenomenon is called masking.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - +1 for the references.