# Joint pdf of a continuous and a discrete rv

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution, censoring

Let us consider a manufacturing system. It involves 2 independent components. If one of these components fails then the entire system fails. Let $Y_j$ be distributed $\exp(Q_j)$ where $j=1, 2$.

If component 1 fails first, then $Y_1$ is observed but $Y_2$ is not ($Y_2$ is censored). If component 2 fails first, then $Y_2$ is observed but Y_1 is not ($Y_1$ is censored). Therefore, if the system fails, we can only observe $u = \min(Y_1, Y_2)$ and the binary random variable $V$, which is $1$ if $Y_1 < Y_2$ and $0$ otherwise.

How can I derive the joint pdf of a continuous variable $u = \min(Y_1, Y_2)$ and a discrete variable $V = 1$ if $Y_1 < Y_2$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Clarifications: first I presume that by $\exp()$ you mean the Exponential distribution, and not the base of the natural logarithms. If yes, then, is $Q_j$ the mean value, or the reciprocal of the mean value (because both these widespread parametrizations of the Exponential distribution are unfortunately symbolized the same way).

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that Dr. Sheldon Cooper might appreciate, or one that Leonard or Raj would be satisfied with?

Comment: Thanks for your responses but I still couldn't find out the joint distribution (or density). This is supposed to be a mixture model.But what is f(u,v) =? Then I will find the marginal pdf of f(v) and f(u), and prove if u and v are independent or not.

Comment: @cardinal Actually, people with Master's degrees from MIT are themselves likely to be able to provide a completely correct answer to the question, though it would certainly not be satisfactory to Dr Sheldon Cooper under any circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Sheldon, Sheldon. How comes that you have to ask a question about math to people like *us*?

In survival analysis, your setting is called "competing risk". The joint distribution of the earliest failure time and the type of failure is fully described by the so called "cumulative incidence function" (it even allows for censoring, i.e. no failure until end of time horizon). I am quite sure that you will find relevant information in the literature stated in
[Assumptions and pitfalls in competing risks model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13935/assumptions-and-pitfalls-in-competing-risks-model)

Comment: I think you meant "Sheldon, Sheldon, Sheldon". :-)

Comment: @cardinal: knock, knock, my mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

In simplistic terms, there is no such thing as a joint **density** of a continuous random variable and a discrete random variable because all the probability mass lies
on two straight lines ($v=0$ and $v=1$) and on these lines, the **joint** 
density, being the probability mass per unit *area,* is infinite. On the other
hand, the **line** density of the mass on the two lines
is a (univariate) exponential density (measured in probability mass per unit
*length*).  More specifically, the line density on the line $v=0$ is the density
of $U_2$ and the line density on the line $v=1$ is the density of $U_1$.

Comment: The parameter on the discrete RV is continuous and the joint density can be fully described in reference to this parameter. See my response. Alternatively but equally valid formulation of the joint density as a peicewise function that pivots on the value of V. There's nothing wrong with describing a density that way.

Comment: Rather, you describe this peicewise density as the separate "line densities", but there's nothing wrong with describing the joint density as a peicewise function comprised of these separate densities. It's still a perfectly valid pdf.

Comment: @DavidMarx As pointed out to you already by cardinal, your answer gives the _marginal_ density of $\min(Y_1,Y_2)$ and this marginal density is a valid pdf as you say, but I too do not see how your answer describes the _joint_ density of $\min(Y_1,Y_2)$ and $V$.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a mixture model, specifically a mixture of exponentials. If I understand your problem setup correctly, I believe what you're looking for looks something like this:

$$
u \sim f(x) =
\begin{cases}
f_{Y_1}(x), & V=1 \\
f_{Y_2}(x), & V=0
\end{cases}
$$

or alternatively

$$u \sim f(x) = \theta f_{Y_1}(x) + (1-\theta)f_{Y_2}(x)$$

Where $\theta$ is the expected proportion of samples generated by $Y_1$ (or using your formulation, $\theta = E[V]$).

You can confirm this experimentally. Here's a mixture model with arbitrarily selected parameters `r1`, `r2` and `theta`:

```
n=1e5
theta=.2
v=rbinom(n,1,theta)
r1=5; r2=1
sample=v*rexp(n,r1) + (1-v)*rexp(n,r2)

f=function(x){theta*dexp(x,r1) + (1-theta)*dexp(x,r2)}

plot(density(sample), xlim=c(0,6))
xv=seq(from=0,to=6, length.out=1e4)
lines(xv,f(xv), col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading it, but I don't think this answers the question (at least, head on). This only appears to address the *marginal* density of $u$, not anything related to a joint distribution (or density).